# Pyramid not finding my template files

Tags: python, pyramid, jinja2, pylons

I followed the Pyramid tutorials and everything worked fine. Then I installed jinja2 for Pyramid and added the necessary lines of code to my `development.ini` file. My templates were found at the specified location as expected. They were also rendered as I expected them to be. However, after doing a restart on my computer and then working with Alembic and SQLAlchemy, I went to view my site and now it's not finding the template directory. In specific, the error I am getting is:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

TemplateNotFound: my_project:templates/index.jinja2;     
asset=/Users/John/project/projectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_project-0.0-py2.7.egg/my_project/templates/index.jinja2; 
searchpath=['/Users/John/project/projectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_project-0.0-py2.7.egg/my_project/templates']
```

In my `development.ini` file I have specified:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:my_project
jinja2.directories = my_project:templates
```

For some frame of reference, my file structure looks like this:

```
/project
    /projectenv
        /bin
           /development.ini
        /lib  # where the "python2.7/site-packages/etc." is located
        /my_project
           /my_project  # "main" project folder
               /__init__.py
               /models.py
               /scripts
               /static
               /templates
                   /<the templates I would like to use>
               /views.py
```

Two questions:

1. How do I fix this? For whatever reason my asset specification isn't working as it was, and I'm not sure what to "specify" in order to fix this.
2. When I looked in the `../python2.7/site-packages/my_project-0.0-py2.7.egg/my_project/templates`, I found "remnants" of my files from my "main" `/my_project` directory. In particular, the `templates` folder and it's contents were not present, but, `views`, `models`, `__init__`, etc. were (although any recent updates to these files were not present). When I make updates to the "main" my_project files, Pyramid doesn't recognize those changes. I need to go into my "...2.7.egg" file, and make changes there for Pyramid to recognize them. Why might this be?

Is my `development.ini` file not configured properly? Or, is this something totally unrelated?

I'm baffled, and not sure what to do. Any thoughts, suggestions, and straight up answers are much appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how are you trying to render the template?

Comment: In my views.py file, for example: @view_config(renderer='templates/index.jinja2', route_name='index_handler'). Then I add the routes in my \_\_init\_\_.py file. I also have tried adding the "config.include('pyramid_jinja2')" in \_\_init\_\_ to no avail.

Comment: try this: @view_config(renderer='index.jinja2',route_name='index_handler') no need 'templates/'

Comment: I just tried it, and unfortunately, it didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you ran `python setup.py install` at some point, which caused your project to get installed to the environment's site-packages directory. Removing the "my_project" directories/files from site-packages and running `python setup.py develop` creates a symlink of your project to site-packages and your changes should work instantly. And when the module is properly available in site-packages, the template lookup should work too.

Comment: You just made my day here. Thanks so much. I must've ran that "setup.py install" command accidentally or...something. Ahhhh. But anyway, everything's back to normal. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

or just by adding

```
config.add_jinja2_search_path("templates")
```

into your pyramid configuration